# Flyway does not seem to recognize java/scala migrations

Tags: scala, flyway

I am using Flyway version 5.2.4 in a scala project and have all my migration scripts are under src/main/resources/db/migrations with the following folder structure

```
main

-resources

--db

---migrations

----V1__example1.sql

----V2__example2.sql

----V3__scala_migration.scala
```

locations is set to db.migrations (Without any prefix. Flyway documentation says if no prefix is used then sql/java migrations are supported)

V1 and V2 seem to get picked up without issues. But V3 is being ignored. I tried adding a V3__java_migration.java as well and it made no difference. Did anyone have any kind luck adding non-sql migrations?

Here is the scala code in the migration

```
package db.migration

import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.{ BaseJavaMigration, Context }

class V3__scala_migration extends BaseJavaMigration {

  override def migrate(context: Context): Unit = {

    val conn = context.getConnection

    conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(
      """
        |DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;

        |CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users`

        |`name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

        |`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

        |PRIMARY KEY (`email`)

        |)ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

        |INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`) ('john','john@example.com');

      """.stripMargin)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must move your Scala or Java migration scripts to the according directories.
[image: directory strucure]

For Scala this would be `src/main/scala/db/migration`

See here the documentation: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migrations#discovery-1

Comment: That did the trick! Should have used this line  "package db.migration" in the scala migration code as a hint to move the script to src/main/scala/db/migration